# Find the nearest value

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm looking for a way to find out which value is closest to x in a table and return that.

Lets assume, for a second, X is x=15, we have the table with 4 values {12, 190, 1, 18}, How do I make it so in this case the first key&value is returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = 15
table = {190, 1, 12, 18}

function NearestValue(table, number)
    local smallestSoFar, smallestIndex
    for i, y in ipairs(table) do
        if not smallestSoFar or (math.abs(number-y) < smallestSoFar) then
            smallestSoFar = math.abs(number-y)
            smallestIndex = i
        end
    end
    return smallestIndex, table[smallestIndex]
end

index, value = NearestValue(table,x)

print(index)
print(value)
```

Comment: Maybe it should be "return table[smallestIndex]" to get the actual value rather than its index.

Comment: Well, he wanted to get "key&value". I edited it to simply return both values.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
 initialdiff = 1000000000000
 selectedkey = -1
 values = {12, 190, 1, 18}
 x = 15

 for key, val in pairs (values) do
     currentdiff = math.fabs(val - x)
     if (currentdiff < initialdiff) do
         initialdiff = currentdiff
         selectedkey = key
     end
 end

 -- selectedkey now holds key for closest match
 -- values[selectedkey] gives you the (first) closest value
```